# The most common word in spaceless string

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a very long string of text that is many words separated by camelCase like so:

`AedeagalAedilityAedoeagiAefaldnessAegeriidaeAeginaAeipathyAeneolithicAeolididaeAeonialAerialityAerinessAerobia`

I need to find the most common word and the number of times it has been used, I am unaware how to do this due to the lack of spaces and being new to C#.

I have tried many methods but none seem to work, any advice you have I'd be very grateful.

I have a github repo with the file being downloaded and a few tests already done here: https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/C-code-test

Thank you.

Comment: Other than regex could be approach with iterating over string `foreach (char c in text)` and checking character for upper case by `if (char.IsUpper(c))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try querying the string with a help of regular expressions and Linq:

```
 string source = ...

 var result = Regex
   .Matches(source, "[A-Z][a-z]*")
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .GroupBy(word => word)
   .Select(group => (word : group.Key, count : group.Count()))
   .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.count)
   .First();

 Console.Write($"{result.word} appears {result.count} time");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dimitry. You make it look so easy!

Answer (score 1):

A non-linq approach using for loop and IsUpper to separate the words.

```cs
string data = "AedeagalAedilityAedoeagiAefaldness";
var words = new List<string>();
var temp = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0;i < data.Length;i++)
{
    temp.Append(data[i]);
    if (i == data.Length-1 || char.IsUpper(data[i+1]))
    {
        words.Add(temp.ToString());
        temp.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest `temp.Clear();` instead of `temp = new StringBuilder();`

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(exampleString, "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])");
var result = split.GroupBy(s => s)
                  .Where(g=> g.Count()>=1 )
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .Select(g => new{ Word = g.Key, Occurrences = g.Count()});
```

var result will contain pairs of (Word, Occurrences) for all words.

If you want just the first one (the one with the most occurrences) use

```
var result = split.GroupBy(s => s)
                  .Where(g=> g.Count()>=1 )
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .Select(g => new{ Word = g.Key, Occurrences = g.Count()}).First();
```

Have in mind that it can happen that you have 2 or more words with the same number of occurrences, so using First() would only give you one of those.